# Slack Bot Replying to his own message in Node js

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

I am trying to make a slack bot in nodejs that replys the user based on their input. But As far now the bot keeps replying to his own messages

this is the code for my bot

```
let Bot = require('slackbots');

// create a bot
let settings = {
    token: 'xoxb-10584202949',
name: 'BotHelp'};

let bot = new Bot(settings);
bot.on('start', function() {

  bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'At your service');

    });

bot.on('message',function (data) {
  console.log(data);
    if (data.username != "BotHelp" && data.subtype != 'bot_message'){
     bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'Yoooo');
    }
});
```

**The Console log for data** **Prints**

```
{ type: 'hello' }
{ text: 'At your service',
  username: 'BotHelp',
  bot_id: 'B336WGVSM',
  type: 'message',
  subtype: 'bot_message',
  team: 'T2ZAW44P3',
  user_team: 'T2ZAW44P3',
  channel: 'C303W2D4M',
  ts: '1479877794.000266' }
{ type: 'presence_change',
  presence: 'active',
  user: 'U33QS0VEF' }
```

**So why my validation is failing to check that the message has been sent from bot itself or not?**

Thank you for your time

Comment: What makes you think validation is failing?

Comment: @MathewJibin because it keeps posting Yooo in an infinite loop in my general chat room

Comment: Are you sure `data.username` & `data.subtype` are as expected? sending sending them in the message or print it in the console.

Comment: So, when you say "the console log for data prints" is that three separate console logs for `data`? Because if so two of those `data`s don't even have `username` or `subtype` in them, making them undefined, and `undefined != "BotHelp"` so your condition check will be passed and the message will be sent. If this is the case `on('message')` is probably not just for actual chat messages, but  generally for any kind of data being passed to the bot by slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. The message event in *slackbots* fires for every event ie, user_typing, message_marked, desktop_notification. All events can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/events). 
Now what i did to ensure my bot didn't send a message after receiving its own was:

```
bot.on('message',function (data) {
   if (data.user != "Uxxxxxx" && data.message === 'message'){
       bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'Yoooo');
   }
```

the data.user gives a unique id, you can get this by `console.log(data)` and find your `user` id.

Also, if you want to specify which message you want to listen to, say direct message. `channel` id inside `data` will start with a *D*. For private channels, the channel id starts with *G*

Hope this helps. I know there is much more to do here but this is the basic. And you can grow on this. I know I will be trying to :D

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is already answered but I will like to add my answer, because the slack api has made some changes.

```
 if (data.type !== "message" || data.subtype === 'bot_message' ){
    return;
    }
    else{
        bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'Yoooo');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd check if the parameters are really **user_name** and **subtype** . If it's right, I would try to check the type of the objects that are coming(Maybe there is a cast in objects coming from the Slack api). I've done a [small project](https://github.com/marcogbarcellos/slack-bot-upload) very similar to yours, using the same library slackbots and also a library I built myself,nodejslack(https://github.com/marcogbarcellos/nodejslack) but didn't get this issue.